# 5x5 Rubiks Cube edge algorithm

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I'm following the tutorial on [Ruwix](https://ruwix.com/twisty-puzzles/5x5x5-rubiks-cube-professors-cube/), and either they're making a mistake or I am.  When solving the edges they give the image:
[image: Edge pairing algorithm]

This is my first attempt at a 5x5 and this step confused me for a long time, as it kept messing up my solved edges.  I finally realised that the edge they have marked pink is NOT the one that gets broken, instead it's one further CCW.  So instead of the algorithm `u' R U R' u` I find I need to do `Uw' R U R' u` (or have the broken edge further around on the TOP face).

Can anyone confirm this move, or hint at my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The move notation with small letters is ambiguous, as different sources use this to mean different things.

[Ruwix's Advanced Notation page](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/advanced/#doublelayer) explains that they use the small letters to denote a turn of the two outer layers. This notation is often used on the 3x3x3 cube as well.

So yes, the site uses `u` to to mean what you know as `Uw`. For larger cubes they use $U_2$.

Comment: Oh you are freaking kidding me!!  I was following [the 4x4 Ruwix page](https://ruwix.com/twisty-puzzles/4x4x4-rubiks-cube-rubiks-revenge/) which says `Lowercase letters mark inner slice turns. u' = Uw' U`.  Did not expect the same site to use two different notations :(

Comment: @Ian: Ouch! That's a pretty bad inconsistency. The 5x5x5 page itself should at least have a warning or explanation.